# Concatenating an already existing filename to create a new file

Tags: c++, algorithm, strings, file, stream

I had answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54730422/1757805) question from stackoverlow and the code below is code that I wrote to explain to the OP a possible way to achieve what I believe they were looking for.

The general idea that I got from them was that they were trying to open a file with a specified file name and if that file does exist that they in turn wanted to create a new file with the same filename but with extra characters appended to the filename.

This is the small program that I wrote to mimic that behavior.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string originalFilename("out.txt");
    std::string extension(".txt");                  
    std::string nextFilename;
    bool originalFileFound = false;

    // First test to see if original file exist by opening 
    // if so then generate the next usable name
    std::fstream fileIn( originalFilename, std::ios::in );
    unsigned int counter = 0;

    if (fileIn.is_open()) {
        counter++;
        nextFilename = originalFilename.substr( 0, originalFilename.size() - extension.size() ) 
                       + "_" + std::to_string(counter) + extension;
        originalFileFound = true;
    }
    fileIn.close();

    // Generate a few files with the appended number system to 
    // the end of the original filename if the original file was found.
    if ( originalFileFound ) {
        for ( int i = 1; i < 6; i++ ) {
            std::fstream nextFile;
            nextFile.open( nextFilename, std::ios::out );
            if (nextFile.is_open()) {
                nextFile << nextFilename; // Write this before updating...
                counter++;
                nextFilename = nextFilename.substr(0, nextFilename.find_first_of('_') + 1) 
                               + std::to_string(counter) + extension;
            }
            nextFile.close();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to know if there is a more elegant, more efficient and cleaner way to achieve this using modern C++. Writing this simple program in essence was basically self practice to improve my skills with string manipulation and the string's set of library functions and algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

- Prefer RAII-style opening the file in the constructor. You already done that with

  ```
      std::fstream fileIn( originalFilename, std::ios::in );
  ```

  so why not follow the suit with

  ```
      std::fstream nextFile(nextFilename, std::ios::out);
  ```
- There is no need to explicitly `nextFile.close();`. The destructor will take care of it at the end of each iteration.
- There is nothing wrong with the early return. Instead of setting `originalFileFound = true;`, and testing it later on, quit immediately if opening fails. That would spare a boolean flag and a level of indentation.
- Consolidate handling of `nextFilename` in one place. Consider

  ```
      if (!fileIn.is_open()) {
          print_error_message();
          return 1;
      }

      std::string prefix = originalFilename.substr(0, originalFilename.size() - extension.size());

      for (int i = 0, counter = 0; counter < 5; i++) {
          nextFilename = prefix + "_" + std::to_string(i) + extension;
          ....
      }
  ```
- I would be very cautious to use this program, because it may overwrite existing files.

Comment: I truly appreciate the feed back. Using a temp string for prefix does make the code look a little more cleaner and concise. And yes I know that this could potentially overwrite existing files, but as I stated it was just a demonstration program to an already existing question over at stackoverflow. I could turn this into a function that would take file manipulation flags as arguments, such as appending, overwriting etc.